# Can a SaltStack sls file use postfix set_main to set a variable in main.cf?

Tags: salt-stack

Can I set `relayhost = [1.2.3.4]` in /etc/postfix/main.cf via a salt sls file equivalent to the salt command below?

> salt 'mymachine.*' postfix.set_main relayhost "[1.2.3.4]"

If so what would the sls file contents be?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there's a built-in state for this. Though you may want to use [postfix-formula](https://github.com/saltstack-formulas/postfix-formula) . Salt-formulas are explained in a [doc](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/development/conventions/formulas.html)

After installing a formula you will be able to set a `relayhost` from pillar. Example Salt top.sls:

```
base:
  '*':
    - postfix
    - postfix.config
```

Please note `postfix.config` state that actually manages the configuration files.

Pillar will look as follows:

```
postfix:
  config:
    relayhost: "[1.2.3.4]"
```